# I'm getting empty array without using session object. How we can get cart data without using session object

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php, php-7.4

I'm getting empty array without using session object. How we can get cart data without using session object.

**Here is the screenshot:**

[image]

**Here is the code:**

$cartItems = $this->cart->getAllVisibleItems();

Comment: Hi @Alan
Which class/interface you are using for the cart object?

Comment: Alan, could you please try the solution provided below.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that you are accessing allVisibleItems directly from the cart object. But first, you should retrieve the quote and then access allVisibleItems. This will resolve your issue.

**Here is the correct code:**

```
$this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can can get cart data using this:-

```
$items = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

Comment: yess thta's the correct